# java.io.FileNotFoundException in FileInputStream with qualified file name

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Getting below Error with following Code:
I'm passing thefile name with full add in FileInputStream constructor.
Ex-: 
    localhost:8080/projectName/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/example.doc

```
logger.info("File Path: "+ path+"/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/"+fileName);

POIFSFileSystem  fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new 
                 FileInputStream(path+"/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/"+fileName));
```

```
http:\localhost:8080\projectName\OuterFolder\InnerFloder\Example.doc (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.avi.service.UserService.createPolicy(UserService.java:1339)
    at com.avi.service.UserService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$de8fbe27.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
    at com.avi.service.UserService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7c22f094_2.createPolicy(<generated>)
    at com.avi.controller.TestController.openPolicy(TestController.java:2733)
```

Comment: Shouldn't "Example.doc" be inside the double quotes(in the second line) ?

Comment: What is the log output? What is `path`?

Comment: path is a string variable having full path like:-
http://localhost:8080/projectName/

Comment: @Andreas: here is the logger output-
**File Path: http://localhost:8080/projectName/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/Example.doc**

Comment: @Avi See shyams answer below

Answer (score 3):

```
http:\localhost:8080\projectName\OuterFolder\InnerFloder\Example.doc
```

Is not a valid file path. On windows there is no "drive" letter "http:" like "C:".
In fact I doubt, an "InnerFloder" exists too.

If you get it from a web application, use the following `in`:

```
URL url = new URL(path + "/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/Example.doc");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

---

To write the file somewhere (you cannot write it back to the web app `http://...`), select a file:

```
File file = new File("C:/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/" + fileName);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // Create any missing directories
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
fs.writeFileSystem(out);
out.close();
```

This is a new file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `url.openStream()`?

Comment: its working @Joop but it's not working with `FileWriter` class

Comment: @AdrianJandl: you are right. It should be `url.openStream()` 
because a static reference to the non-static method openStream() from the type URL

Comment: Same exception with 
`FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(path+"/downloads/policies/currentASC.doc")`
  and URL can't be use with `FileWriter` class.

Comment: @AdrianJandl : corrected, thanks. @Avi: with `http:` there need not exist any file on the file system. I have extended the answer; FileWriter (all with ...Writer/Reader) is for text, `.doc` is binary data and hence one needs `...Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

`FileInputStream` needs an actual file path in the file system not a URL.

Comment: It is right??  **localhost:8080/projectName/OuterFolder/InnerFloder/example.doc**

Comment: No, `localhost:8080/...` is not a valid local path name